# PL/SQL Syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: plsql, syntax, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know how to get `Visual Studio 2015` to recognize that a file is `PL/SQL` and `highlight keywords` etc?

I have installed the `Oracle extension` which makes the PL/SQL language show up under `Text Editor` Languages. 
However I cannot find a way to `link` that language for syntax highlighting to a file extension.

I have tried `Text Editor-->File Extension` to add that way but that allows you to select an editor rather than a language, what I am looking for is Simple Text editor with PL/SQL Syntax highlighting in `Visual Studio`.

Comment: I have not found any for VS 2015. But there is one for VS Code, one for Notepad++, but only syntax highlighting is not enough. I am using Oracle since 2001 and have never edited PL/SQL code in VS. Get SQL Developer. It is free.

Comment: I do have SQL Developer I was hoping for something suitable for quickly opening a PL SQL script from TFS in Visual Studio Team Explorer to make it more readable. I would tend to do development in SQL Developer its just a bit cumbersome swapping between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get some basic syntax highlighting, simply for colors on keywords, not using it for compilation.

`Tools => Options => Text Editor => File Extension`

1. Extension: `pkb` (this is our package body file extension)
2. Set the editor to `Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, T-SQL Editor`...I assume
   you would need to install SSDT as part of the VS install.
3. Click Apply to add it to the list.
4. Repeat for each PLSQL file extension

Initially this didn't work, so I changed it to the editor: `Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, T-SQL Editor (with encoding)` then changed it back and I got the colors.
[image: extensioneditor]
[image: editor]

Comment: It's only going to recognise some of the keywords. Better than nothing though I guess.

Comment: Very nice, thanks for sharing!!!! Worked for me with Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Just one thing, it is not available when you are comparing version of the files in TFS/Git